# How can I make sure that the fixed modal is on top and that the top of the modal is also visible when the user scrolls?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, css-position, chakra-ui

Here is the code I have. Could you please help me create a more comprehensible version?

```
import { LoginProps } from '@/layouts/layout.props';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Divider,
  Flex,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Heading,
  HStack,
  IconButton,
  Input,
  Link,
  Stack,
  Text,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { MdClose } from 'react-icons/md';
import { PasswordField } from './PasswordField';

export const LoginModal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }: LoginProps) => (
  <Flex
    bg={'#00000030'}
    w={'full'}
    h={'full'}
    p={'15px'}
    pos={'fixed'}
    top={0}
    left={0}
    opacity={showModal ? 1 : 0}
    visibility={showModal ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
    alignItems={'center'}
    transition={'all 0.3s ease-out'}
    justifyContent={'center'}
    overflow={'auto'}
    zIndex={99999}
  >
    {showModal && (
      <Box w={'full'} height={'full'} pos={'absolute'} top={0} left={0} onClick={() => setShowModal(false)} />
    )}
    <Stack
      spacing='8'
      bg={'white'}
      maxW={'380px'}
      w={'full'}
      rounded={'lg'}
      p={{ base: '12px', md: '20px' }}
      pos={'relative'}
      zIndex={100}
    >
      <Stack>
        <Stack textAlign='center'>
          <Flex alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'space-between'} gap={0}>
            <Heading fontSize={{ base: '20px', sm: '24px' }} color={'black'}>
              Добро пожаловать!
            </Heading>
            <IconButton
              w={'10px'}
              h={'10px'}
              onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
              color={'black'}
              bg={'none'}
              icon={<MdClose fontSize={'28px'} />}
              _hover={{
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                transform: 'rotate(540deg)',
              }}
              _active={{
                backgroundColor: 'none',
              }}
              transition={'all 0.5s ease-in-out'}
              aria-label={'Toggle Navigation'}
            />
          </Flex>
          <Text color='#8E9297' textAlign={'start'} fontSize={{ base: '11px', sm: '14px' }}>
            Войти в систему чтобы торговать в системе
          </Text>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
      <Box bg={{ base: 'transparent', sm: 'bg.surface' }} borderRadius={{ base: 'none', sm: 'xl' }}>
        <Stack spacing='12'>
          <Stack color={'#63676C'}>
            <Flex direction={'column'} gap='5'>
              <FormControl w={'full'}>
                <FormLabel htmlFor='login'>Логин</FormLabel>
                <Input
                  id='login'
                  type='text'
                  placeholder='Введите логин'
                  bg={'#F0F3F7'}
                  fontSize={'14px'}
                  fontFamily={'Inter'}
                  variant={'unstyled'}
                  border={'none'}
                  padding='12px'
                  rounded={'8px'}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <PasswordField />
            </Flex>
            <Link display={'inline'} color={'#388ff3'} fontSize={'12px'} fontWeight={400} textDecor={'none'}>
              Забыли пароль?
            </Link>
          </Stack>

          <Stack spacing='2'>
            <Button
              bg={'#388FF3 !important'}
              _hover={{
                background: 'none !important',
                border: '1px #388FF3 solid',
                color: '#388FF3',
              }}
              variant={'solid'}
              color={'white'}
            >
              Войти
            </Button>
            <HStack>
              <Divider />
              <Text whiteSpace='nowrap' color='#8E9297' fontSize={'12px'}>
                Хотите стать продавцом?
              </Text>
              <Divider />
            </HStack>
            <Button
              variant={'outline'}
              borderColor={'#388FF3'}
              color={'#388FF3'}
              _hover={{ bg: '#388FF3', color: 'white' }}
            >
              Подать заявку
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    </Stack>
  </Flex>
);
```

I have included an image that illustrates the error I'm referring to.
[image]

I attempted to use the CSS property `overflow: auto` in my code. I had the expectation that this would enable a scrollbar to appear on the element when its content exceeds its allocated space.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`height: auto` and `overflow: scroll`

Comment: Hey Rasil! Thanks for answering. In this case though the answer is quite short and doesn't fully explain how to use the properties your proposing. Consider adding an example to show how to use it. Thanks!